# File.listFiles() keeps returning null for File[]

Tags: java, arrays, file, recursion, io

I am trying to recursively show all the files in a directory, however, when I try to use the listFiles() method to list the files in an array it keeps returning null. Any ideas to fix this bug?

```java
import java.io.*;
public class Q4 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        File dir = new File("C:/Desktop/468_Quiz_3");
        listAllFiles(dir);

    }
    static void listAllFiles(File dir) {
        if(dir.isFile())
            System.out.println(dir.getName());
        else {
            System.out.println("[" + dir.getName().toUpperCase() + "]");
            File[] files = dir.listFiles();
            for(int i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
                listAllFiles(files[i], " ");
                listAllFiles(files[i]);
            }
        }
    }
    static void listAllFiles(File dir, String spaces) {
        for(File f: dir.listRoots())
            if(f.isDirectory())
                System.out.print(spaces);
    }

}
```

Comment: What do you mean it is returning null ?

Comment: Also folder is also a file you dont need to keep that if condition .

Comment: `listFiles()` does not return `null` if the `File` is a directory. You might get an empty array, but it would not be `null`.

Comment: Incorrect it does return null.  It is for me and I can't on a MAC get this code to work

Answer (score 0):

Use Apache Commons IO instead, specifically FileUtils.listFiles(). It handles nested directories, filters (based on name, modification time, etc).

```
Collection files = FileUtils.listFiles(
  dir, 
  new RegexFileFilter(".*"), 
  DirectoryFileFilter.DIRECTORY
);
```

or use

```
Files.walk(Paths.get("/etc")).filter(Files::isRegularFile).collect(Collectors.toList())
```

Comment: File.walk gives me a really weird error java.nio.file.FileSystemException: Interrupted system call